# Work out remaining singlemailmessage capacity in test

Tags: unit-test, governorlimits, apex-email-service

I have an Apex class that does some complicated decisions surrounding whether to send an e-mail to a user or not, including the fundamental "can we send any more e-mails today" check from Salesforce:

```
try {
    Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
}
```

If I want to then "test" this in the test class, my notion was to have a test method that reserved the "limit for the day" and then called the logic, which would try to reserve one more, and the "false" would be returned, something like:

```
static testMethod void testReserveMailCapacity()
{
    AdvancedCustomController controller = getNewController();

    // consume all available limits
    Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(1000);

    // call method and assert
    System.assert(!controller.methodThatReservesOneMore());
}
```

But this did not work, it told me my reservation **in the test class** was breaking the limit. I eventually found out if I reserved 997, and then ran my method it worked as expected, but why was this? Well, it was because within the rest of this *test class* there are three other test methods that fire/traverse or otherwise cause the reserving of  an EmailCapacity point (I am fairly sure this is the case, anyway!) - which means I have to reserve "less" than the daily limit, as some are being consumed elsewhere. It also seems this can fluctuate anyway (is there any order to test method execution within a class??). Of course this is only ever within the scope of the single test, and the limit is released as soon as it is complete.

I need some way to make a stable assertion as to how many I should reserve, or some other way to test busting this limit in a given scenario?

The Limits class doesn't hold this information (it is not in getLimitEmailInvocations - this is different) and using startTest and stopTest does not clear/protect this limit (as it is on the "daily" scope, one presumes?)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're testing a daily limit, you get one of those limits for one run of your test.  So, that one limit set gets counted against for each test method, and no, you can't predefine the test execution order.  (I'm pretty sure Salesforce gives each test method to a different thread, so all the test methods are running in parallel / concurrently.)

My suggestion is to write some static variables/methods to manage the EmailCapacity.  And then in every test method, if you use send an Email, document it with the static methods.

For example:

```
@isTest
public class testClass{
    public static integer dailyEmailCapacity=1000;
    public static integer numberOfEmailsSent=0;

    public static integer getNumberOfEmailsAvailable(){
        return dailyEmailCapacity-numberOfEmailsSent;
    }//END getNumberOfEmailsAvailable()

    public static boolean canSendEmail(){
        if(getNumberOfEmailsAvailable()>0)
            return true;
        return false;       
    }//END canSendEmail()

    public static void recordSendEmailResult(list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailList){
        if(emailList==null)
            return;
        numberOfEmailsSent+=emailList.size();
    }//END recordSendEmailResult(list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailList)

    // ---------  test methods  ------------


}//END testClass
```

Comment: This is a very interesting solution, I will try to give this a spin this morning.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe wrap all the calls to Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity in your own class and then use `Test.isRunningTest()` to simulate the required responses for the test case.

Essentially mock out the required responses and then let the test case have some control of the response.

Comment: Ah, cheers Daniel, I had forgotten about isRunningTest(), I will see if I can bake that into a solution..

Comment: Thanks for your input Daniel, a worthy reminder to the runningTest context, but I will have to accept amators answer as having actually implemented from this code samples, it does "technically" answer the question of working out remaining limits more directly (rather than circumnavigating the need ;) )